# Programing Language availability for a Mac

Tags: macos, development, language

I want an inexpensive programming language for my Mac. I know Pascal, Fortran, some familiarity with C. I don’t know many recent languages but am willing learn. I just have a Mac , and I want to experiment with programming again after decades of not doing much. In the future, I might want to do I/O to external devices.

Comment: What is the goal of learning the language?

Comment: I just have a MAC, and I want to experiment with programing again after decades of not doing much. In the future, I might want to do I/O to external devices.

Comment: So just pick one from the ones listed in the answer below and get started. We can‘t make the decision for you.

Comment: ahhh yes actually.. such recommendation questions are off topic on most sites that host programming questions. You could surf Stack overflow developer results to see which technologies are related, their pay grades and popularity etc. https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology @Karpinsky

Answer (score 2):

Most languages are available to learn on a Mac. To my knowledge, most are free or fairly cheap. You can use gcc as a C and Fortran compiler. gcc is free. I program in Fortran and python. Python is free. And Swift is a popular language to program a Mac or iOS device. The popular editors, Atom and Visual Studio Code, are both used to program in many different languages. The editors have add-on extensions to program these languages. There are extensions for Ruby, python, Fortran, c, javascript, java, Perl, PHP, Lua, and others.

Comment: inexpensive could also refer to resources (softwares required, storage used, processor heavy, if something like that exists) used. I feel that the question is unclear.